# why do we use jvm arguments for debugging "server=y"?

Tags: debugging, jvm, remote-debugging, jvm-arguments

While debugging with java codes when we pass the arguments there is one argument i.e. server=y
why do we use it? Can someone please give all the details about it???

I used the arguments as below-
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4010,server=y,suspend=y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html):

> If "y", listen for a debugger application to attach; otherwise, attach to the debugger application at the specified address.
>
> If "y" and no address is specified, choose a transport address at which to listen for a debugger application, and print the address to the standard output stream.

So in short, it tells the application to act like a server and listen for a debugger.